# onclick html images for partial page refresh java script

Tags: asp.net, html

I have an html image, and I am trying to figure out if it is possible to do a partial page refresh when someone clicks on the image.  I was thinking I would use a javascript. I am using aspx, and mvc model

Here is my thought

```
<img id = "Img1" , alt = "Click me"  src = /content/img1.gif/>
```

my script would look something like

```
<script type = "text/javascript" src ="../../Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.js" >
    $(function()
    {
        $("#Img1").click(function()
        {
            $('#updatePartialView'). load('@Url.Action("myAction", "myController")');
        });
     });
</script>
```

but it doesn't seem to want to work, I don't even know if it is possible .

--Update per Comment 
I have a series of images  on the top, and when the user click on the images the bottom half of the page refreshes with information about that picture.

---update so  I wanted to try something different but it doesn't work see below

```
   <script type = "text/javascript" src ="../../Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.js" >
          $(function()
           {
             $("#Img1").click(function()
           {
                alert("I clicked this"); 
            });
         });
     </script>
```

Comment: You want to reload the img onclick?

Comment: I'm not clear on what a partial page is. Can you explain what your trying to do?

Comment: put your function in separate **script** tag.  And remove ');' in your end of function.

Comment: updated my script still doesn't work

Comment: Separate open and close script tag for your javascript function.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove closing  "`);`" in your end of javascript `myFunction()`. It would be working.

But I would suggest to add the onclick handler as below.

```
<img id = "Img1" alt = "Click me" src="">
```

Script:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript">
   $(function(){
        $("#Img1").click(function(){
            $('#updatePartialView').load('@Url.Action("myAction", "myController")');
        });
     });
</script>
```

Comment: It generate an error saying JsScript Run Time error on the $(funtion()

Comment: Did you include jQuery library file in your page?

Comment: okay i did do that <scrip type ="text/javascript" src = "../../Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.js">